# Detecting each character inputed in field and run conditionals

Tags: javascript

I am building a web app.  I believe it will be easiest if I try to explain what I want the user experience to look like before I ask my question.

I want my user to go on my site and begin to type in a text field.  When each character is inputted, I want to run a conditional statement on that character to decided if it should be added to the text field.  If the character inputted is not one I want, the character isn't added.

I have validations in my model to do this after the text is submited, but I want it to be real time.  I'm guessing this relates to JavaScript and I am not comfortable enough in coding it to know what to search for/research.  Can you assist me in where to look (Tutorials, Concepts, etc)?

Thank you for taking the time to read this.

Comment: Removing references to Ruby on Rails - this question is specific to JavaScript.

Comment: This may help you, although it uses jQuery to do this a bit more efficiently - http://blog.troygrosfield.com/2010/12/01/preventing-character-input-using-javascript/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with the `preventDefault` method on the event object passed to the keydown event. This basically tells the browser to not preform its default action (which on a text field would be appending the letter to the field).

Here is an implementation using jQuery for brevity, but you can implement the same functionality in pure javascript as well:

```
$('input').on('keydown', function(event) {
    // event.which is the character code
    if ( /* some condition */ ) event.preventDefault();
});
```

And here is a fiddle with an example where you cannot type the letter A: http://jsfiddle.net/354XJ/

Answer (score 0):

It's not *precisely* your situation but a very good starting point would be this question and its answers: [How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/995183/385532)

You are basically looking for javascript that will intercept the keypress and only allow it if it is an allowed key, the question above implements this for numeric keys - start with that and expand it as per your needs.